# stackdriver Request contains an invalid argument

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I'm studying about Google Cloud Platform.

In this [stackdriver projects.groups.members.list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.groups.members/list) I'm trying to get member's list in stackdriver's group.

when I command this code in above link,I get this error.

```
GET https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/{my_project}/groups/{my_group}/members?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

error :

```
{  
  "error": {
    "code": 400,   
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",   
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"  
  } 
}
```

my_project and my_group is correct, and there is no other argument, is there any problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that {my_group} is not alphabetical string like `my_group`,

but integer string like `12345678956`.

in this [projects.groups.list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.groups/list) you can find your group_id by excuting APIs Explorer.